# Changes in Visual Studio don't affect Unreal Engine

Tags: c#, visual-studio, arkit, unreal-engine4, live-streaming

I'm using:

Unreal Engine 4.23 / AppleARKit

Visual Studio 2019

I'm trying to modify the variable of a class inside an existing and working Unreal Engine Project. This variable is used to define the Subject Name of an Unreal Engine Live Link Source. When I use the built app to connect to Unreal Engine the "Subject Name" (e.g. "iPhoneXFaceAR") is shown inside the Unreal Engine Editor.

In Visual Studio the default setting is defined inside the AppleARKitSettings.h file:

```
UCLASS(Config=Engine, defaultconfig)
class APPLEARKIT_API UAppleARKitSettings :
    public UObject,
    public FSelfRegisteringExec
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    UAppleARKitSettings()
        : LivelinkTrackingType(ELivelinkTrackingType::None)
        , bFaceTrackingLogData(false)
        , bFaceTrackingWriteEachFrame(false)
        , FaceTrackingFileWriterType(EARFaceTrackingFileWriterType::None)
        , bShouldWriteCameraImagePerFrame(false)
        , WrittenCameraImageScale(1.f)
        , WrittenCameraImageQuality(85)
        , LiveLinkPublishingPort(11111)
        , DefaultFaceTrackingLiveLinkSubjectName(FName("iPhoneXFaceAR"))

        etc...
```

**Attempt 1**:
I change it to "Test" inside of Visual Studio:

```
DefaultFaceTrackingLiveLinkSubjectName(FName("Test"))
```

I compile the app but it still shows up as "iPhoneXFaceAR" when I connect to Unreal Engine.

**Attempt 2**:
I read that the "Config=Engine" means I can set this variable inside my project's .../Config/DefaultEngine.ini file.
So I added this code:

```
DefaultFaceTrackingLiveLinkSubjectName="Test"
```

This worked. I could see the change inside Unreal Engine. But... I need to be able to set this variable from inside the app, so this way won't work for my purpose.

**Attempt 3**:

I guessed maybe I'm not using Visual Studio correctly so I tried a number of different things:

1. I pressed the compile button inside Unreal Engine and nothing happened.
2. Visual Studio > Rebuild Solution.
3. Rebuild the app.
4. *Result*: still shows as "iPhoneXFaceAR"
5. Deleted .vs, Intermediate, and Saved directories.
6. Right-click .uproject file > Generate Visual Studio project files.
7. Open the .sln in Visual Studio > Build > Rebuild Solution.
8. Rebuild the app.
9. *Result*: still shows as "iPhoneXFaceAR"

Somehow even though I change it, it still decides to use "iPhoneXFaceAR". The "iPhoneXFaceAR" string cannot be found anywhere else inside the entire solution so I don't understand why this is not working.

**So my question is**:

Why am I able to change this variable inside of the DefaultEngine.ini but not directly using Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that the application is pulling the value from the DefaultFaceTrackingLiveLinkSubjectName key in the ini file. Search your project for where this key is read and set the value yourself instead of using the value supplied by the ini.

Comment: Hi Edney, I found out this could be edited from the ApplARKit Project Settings inside of the Unreal Engine Editor. Somehow, even though I modified the source could it was retaining the "iPhoneXFaceAR" in the Project Settings and using that to compile the app. I changed it there and it worked.